# How to send props to reactjs when Redirect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm trying to send props when redirecting to a route via React Route (Redirect to) but the component(SideBar) does not receive any props. How should I send props and how do I receive props in the component? I want to send a prop from the current state.

ParentComponent (WelcomeScreen.tsx)

```
render(){

    return (  
        this.state.idUser != -1 ?  <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/Activities',
            state: { referrer: this.state.idUser }
            }}/> :   
        <div>
            {this.renderHeader()}
            <div className='screenUser'>
                {this.renderPanelUpButtons()}
                {this.renderWelcomeMenu()}
            </div>
        </div>

    );
```

Activities.tsx

```
export interface ActivitiesProps {
idUser: number;
}

interface ActivitiesState {  
message: string;
activitiesFirstPart: IActivity[];
activitiesSecondPart: IActivity[];
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newprops : ActivitiesProps){
    if(newprops!== this.props){
        this.props = newprops;
    }

}
```

Here the component will not receive any props.

To be easier to understant I put also the routes;

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="hangouts-body">
            <div>
                <Route path="/" exact={true} component={WelcomeScreen} />
                <Route path="/Groups" exact={true} component={Groups} />
                <Route path="/Activities" exact={true} component={Activities} />
                <Route path="/OneActivity" exact={true} component={OneActivity} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Getting props via url is a bit different in React.
The following lines explain the process in a nutshell

routes part:

```
<Route path="/Activities/:idUser" exact={true} component={Activities} />
```

redirect part:

```
<Redirect to={`/Activities/${this.state.idUser}`}/>
```

getting props part

```
props.match.params.idUser
```

Answer (score 1):

What i have done to pass data without showing it to user is by using history prop,

```
this.props.history.push({
             pathname:"/shopdetail",
             state:{
                 key:"value"
              }
            });
```

And in the ShopDetail component you can access the object like,

```
this.props.location.state.key
```

Answer (score 1):

As simple as send it in the to:object, check the docs https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md

`<Redirect
        to={{
           pathname: "/login",
           state: {
            from: props.location
           }
        }}
      />`

then can be accessed via this.props.location.state.from

Comment: The component specified by the <Route> that is the target of the <Redirect> must be a class derived from React.Component<RouteComponentProps, YourStateInterface>, not a functional component. The class defines properties for props that contains location.state where <Redirect to={{ state }}/> ends up. The functional component has no way to retrieve that information, as of React Router 5. That's using TypeScript with React.