# How to pass data to a page within a <redirect> in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Right now I am redirecting to a new page using  but I dont know how to pass the data to the new page. This is what I am doing:-

```
class ShopsCatOptions extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={            
            shopd: this.props.shop,
            redirect:false

        };        
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.redirect) {
            return <Redirect push to="./shopdetail" data={this.state.redirect}/>;
        }

        return(
            <div class="expndinnerm" onClick={this.handleOnClick}>
            {
                this.state.shopd        
            }
            </div>
        )
    }

}
export default ShopsCatOptions
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: You could pass the data through a common ancestor. Or you could use redux. Or you could try the new context api, not very intuitive IMHO but that's a good use case for it I think.

Comment: is there no simple implementation like this:-
<Redirect push to="./shopdetail" data={this.state.redirect}/>

Comment: The only "simple" way I can think of, is to add the parameters to the URL and get them using `props.match.params.theParamName` . This would only work with strings though

Comment: then how to send it in params if I wish to send this.state.redirect value to './shopdetail'

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48233848/1362366) is how.

Comment: thanks that helped!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What i have done to acheive this is by using history prop,

```
this.props.history.push({
             pathname:"/shopdetail",
             state:{
                 key:"value"
              }
            });
```

And in the ShopDetail component you can access the object like,

```
this.props.location.state.key
```

Edit: To get history in your props, your main component should have ,

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
...
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/user" component={User} />
    <Route path="*" component={page404} />
  </Switch>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Be aware though that the component will be different if someone opens the link directly in his browser than if someone navigates from within the app.

Comment: Component wont be different but the props wont be available if opened directly as the first page of the application from the browser

Comment: i get props.history is undefined how to fix it

Comment: to get history in your props, you have to have <BrowserRouter> in your main, <App> component